# How to change a keycode using setkeycodes

Tags: keyboard, xorg, thinkpad

I have a Thinkpad Edge E130 running Sabayon (a Gentoo-based distro), and I'm fighting the well-know bug **Xorg 255 keycodes limit**.

My laptop has the Fn+F4 hotkey for *Mic Mute/Unmute*. This is the problem:

- `showkey -k` shows keycode **248** on Fn+F4 keypress
- `showkey -s` shows nothing on keypress
- `xev` shows nothing on keypress (because 248+8 [added by kernel] is bigger than 255)

If a key has a keycode, it must have a scancode too. With [getscancodes](http://keytouch.sourceforge.net/dl-getscancodes.html) program indeed I got 26 as scancode:

```
# ./Sabayon/getscancodes/getscancodes /dev/input/event6 
Input driver version is 1.0.1
Input device ID: bus 0x19 vendor 0x17aa product 0x5054 version 0x4101
Input device name: "ThinkPad Extra Buttons"
26 (0x1a)
26 (0x1a)
```

According to [this](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?p=1536096#post1536096) thread, my guess is simply to change the keycode of the hotkey with a smaller, unused one. For example 120 seems to be unused according to my `$ xmodmap -pke`

I have tried with

```
# setkeycodes 0x1a 120
```

but without success, the keycode is always 248 checking with `showkey`.

How is the proper way to change keycodes?